# Hide trend line in amcharts4

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts4

How to hide the trendline on legend click event in amcharts4?

```js
legend.itemContainers.template.events.on("hit", function(ev) {
  for (var l = 0; l < series.dataItems._values.length; l++) {
    if (ev.target.dataItem.dataContext['name'] === series.dataItems._values[l].categories.categoryX) {
      if (ev.target.dataItem.dataContext.visible) {
        series.dataItems._values[l].hide();
        series.dataItems._values[l].segment._baseId = ""
      } else {
        series.dataItems._values[l].show();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 for (var l = 1; l < series._chart._dataUsers._values.length; l++) {
            if (ev.target.dataItem.dataContext['fill'] === series._chart._dataUsers._values[l]._data[0].color) {
                if (ev.target.dataItem.dataContext.visible) {
                    series._chart._dataUsers._values[l].hide();
                }
                else {
                    series._chart._dataUsers._values[l].show();
                }
            }
        }
```